# C# Safe Navigation Operator to avoid divide by zero exceptions

Tags: c#, excel

I'm creating an excel report that calculates the weighted average cost across a span of months. This is for 100+ months, and some of these months do not have any quantity. If the month doesn't have a quantity, I set it to 0 to avoid a null exception error.

When generating the report I get a divide by zero exception for those months without a quantity.  Is there a way to check if the value is 0 in a sum calculation using the safe navigation (.?) operator?

Here's what I've tried, to no avail:

Setting the property to 0m if the quantity is null :

```
     WeightedQty = (x.Item2 / 100m) * x.Item1?.qty ?? 0m
```

Doing the sum calculation where I get the divide by zero error:

```
     WeightedCost = accrual_qtys.Sum(y => y.Quantity * key.wac) /  accrual_qtys.Sum(y => y.WeightedQty == 0m ? y.WeightedQty : 1m)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
 WeightedCost = accrual_qtys.Sum(y => y.Quantity * key.wac) /  (accrual_qtys.Any(y => y.WeightedQty > 0m) ? accrual_qtys.Sum(y => y.WeightedQty) : 1m))
```